# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid prop `stripe` supplied to `Elements`. We recommend using the `loadStripe` utility from `@stripe/stripe-js`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm SO frustrated. I'm literally implementing straight from the Stripe Docs, and I keep getting the error

`Error: Invalid prop 'stripe' supplied to 'Elements'. We recommend using the 'loadStripe' utility from '@stripe/stripe-js'`

... but I am! What is wrong with this script? I've searched everywhere, and can not find any reason why I'm getting this error.

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import {CardElement, Elements, useElements, useStripe} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';

const stripePromise = loadStripe('pk_test_yesItsMyRealKey')

class MembershipCheckout extends 

React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
        <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
        </Elements>
    )
  }
}


export default MembershipCheckout;
```

package.json

```
"@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.1.2",
"@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.11.0",
```

Not sure if it matters, but i'm using Rails 6, with react-rails and webpacker

Comment: Do you have any other component "Element" anywhere?

Comment: Hey! Is this the entirety of your code? I tried to paste this into a CodeSandbox because everything you've done here looks correct, but I can't replicate the error. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-stripe-js-minimal-forked-4i4j7

Comment: Seconded: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-hill-8cr0j?file=/src/App.js, are you sure the code you're running is up to date?

Comment: @Nikita Chayka No other Element anywhere.

Comment: @LMulvey Yes it's the whole code.

Comment: @ttmarek What does 'are you sure the code you're running is up to date' mean?

Comment: Wow I'm a freaking moron. I still had `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>` in my app layout header, which is what was causing this error. This error message is misleading. This link helped me realize that https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js/issues/56#issuecomment-592947778

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow I'm a freaking moron. I still had
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>`

in my app layout header, which is what was causing this error. This error message is misleading. [This link helped me realize that](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js/issues/56#issuecomment-592947778)

Comment: Amazing, I'm a moron too!

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have loaded the stripe script from your index.html.
if so, please remove it. The method you use works for react library only and creates incompatibility if you load another Stripe library via index.html.

Comment: I already solved the issue, and I wrote the solution in the comments above.

Comment: so, please write the answer and mark it as the correct one, so others will look at the topic as one with a solution. with regards.
not many looks at the comments to an answer which has not been tagged as helpful